# Output multi-line return from PS into single cell in Excel

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have written a very basic script to poll machines for certain bits of information.  It works perfectly except when the results from a single machine have multiple entries.  For example, I am scanning for monitor connections and everything exports to excel just fine unless the PC being scanned has more than one monitor connected.  More specifically, a PC with one DP connected gives me "10" just fine.  When a PC has 2 DP monitors, in PS, I get:

```
"10"
"10"
```

But excel gives me `System.Object[]`.

So, how do I get multi-line results to either, both land in the same cell with a proper return carriage or how do I get them to each get their own cell but only have the machine name outputted once?

Here is the script I am using and I am definitely a PS novice so keep that in mind while wondering why I might be doing something silly.

```
Get-Content C:\temp\hostnames.txt | ForEach {

    $details = Invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorconnectionparams -Namespace root\wmi | ForEach-Object VideoOutputTechnology -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } 

    if ( $details ) {

        $props = @{
            ComputerName = $_
            DisplayType = $details
        }

        New-Object PsObject -Property $props
    }

    Else {    
        $props = @{
            ComputerName = $_
            DisplayType = 'Unavailable'
        }

        New-Object PsObject -Property $props
    }

} | Sort ComputerName | Export-Csv C:\temp\Monitor_Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

[`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) and its in-memory counterpart, [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv), do not meaningfully support objects with properties that contain *collections*, such as arrays.

If you want to
represent all collection elements in a single CSV column value, you'll have to create a string representation of the collection yourself, which in your case means joining the elements of the (potential) `$details` array with `` "`n" `` (a LF newline) or `` "`r`n" `` (a CRLF newline), using `-join`, the [string joining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join).

Here's a simplified example (using `ConvertTo-Csv` to print the results immediately):

```
$details = '10', '10'  # sample input array

# Use -join "`n"` to create multiline string from the array,
# with each (stringified) element on its own line.
[pscustomobject] @{ DisplayType = $details -join "`n" } | 
  ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output:

```
"DisplayType"
"10
10"
```

Note how the multiline value is represented as a *single* column value, due to enclosure in `"..."`.

Also note the use of a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) *literal* - `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` - which is the preferred (more concise and efficient) way to create `[pscustomobject]` (aka `[psobject]`) instances in PowerShell v3+.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this. First method adds output in one field in the CSV file. Filtering in Excel can still be leveraged via the filter "Contains…" or multi column filtering.

```
$data = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()
$array = 'SRV1','SRV2','SRV3'
$data.Add([PSCustomObject] @{
    SingularValue = 'TestArray'
    MultipleValues = $array | Join-String -Separator "`n"
})
```

In the second method, every value gets it own row, but other columns are duplicated. This results in more rows, but you can filter them more easily.

```
$data = [System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]::new()
$array = 'SRV1','SRV2','SRV3'
$array | ForEach-Object {
    $data.Add([PSCustomObject] @{
    SingularValue = 'TestArray'
    MultipleValues = $_
})}
```